# Use Bootstrap theme in Symfony 3

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I want to use Bootstrap Paper theme as main theme in my Symfony 3. But I dont know to include it correctly.

Comment: You want the theme as a general HTML theme? That would be basic HTML, please do some more research on the topic. Look for `HTML stylesheets`, `css` and any basic HTML Webpage tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `asset()` Function within your Template like so:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" />

 <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

[Reference Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)